# How to check EXISTS result - PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I use a http://php.net/ page code for conecting with PDO. I Add the EXIST term. How to check if the EXISTS return false? If is not posible, how to check if select return an empty result?

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=xxxx", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully";
            getUsers($conn,$po[0]);
            $conn = null;
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

function getUsers($con,$po){

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id FROM webs WHERE name='$po')";

     foreach ($con->query($sql) as $row) {

         print $row['nombre'] . "\n";
         print $row['id'] . "\n";
         print $row['email'] . "\n";
     }

}
```

Comment: PDO query return a PDOStatement. It has a method called rowCount that return the number of rows affected by the last statement. See http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WHERE EXISTS` returns a standard `SELECT` result (rows) based on the subquery after key `EXISTS`

So, to check if the `EXISTS` fails, you have to use `rowCount`, that return the number of rows returned by the query:

```
$result = $con->query($sql);
if( $result->rowCount() > 0 ) echo "EXISTS";
else                          echo "NOT EXISTS";
```

(Edit:)

#### Please note:

As noted in the comments below, the `rowCount()` works fine in this case and always with mySQL database structures, but «this behaviour is not guaranteed for all database» structures: with sqLite, i.e., it doesn't works.

Comment: "If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases _may_ return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.", although - since the question is about MySQL specifically - it should work.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I know it. In sqlite, i.e., it doen't works. But in this case, it works

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thank you for the warning. I have edited my answer adding a note, because the question title is about generic 'PDO', so my answer can be ambiguous for future visitors

Answer (score 0):

if you will use like this then it will work and no require for check condition

```
$rows = $con->query($sql);
if($rows){
   foreach ($rows as $row) {
         print $row['nombre'] . "\n";
         print $row['id'] . "\n";
         print $row['email'] . "\n";
   }
}
```